# copy image from sandbox and paste it to iPad/ iphone internal memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've using `uiimagepickercontroller` and taken images via camera and stored into folder that was created in sandbox. That stored images are not displayed in iPads or iPhone photo gallery. I want to display those sandbox pictures in device gallery. Any one help me out from this.
My optimum goal is to copy image from sandbox and paste it to device's internal memory.

Comment: If you wan to show image in device gallery then you need stored into image in gallery.

Comment: Are you want to stored image in gallery?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh you are correct I need to know how I can store images in gallery via objective c code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the **UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()** function.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(IMAGE_TO_STORED, nil, nil, nil);
```

Edit:

```
- (IBAction)savedPhoto:(id)sender{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(IMAGE_TO_STORED, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Another way to stored image is:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library saveImage:image toAlbum:nil withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
```